Questions regarding the simple linear regression function

What is the difference between the least squares simple linear regression function and the least squares prediction function?

What is the difference between the simple linear regression function and the best-fitted line function?


My research has not allowed me to find the answer to both questions.
Thank you!!

The answer to both is nothing.

Thank you very much Whuber!
